# What is the point of the null-condition operator in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-core, null-conditional-operator

PowerShell 7 recently moved out of the experimental stage the [Null-conditional (`?.`) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#null-conditional-operators--and-). In playing around with it a bit and reading the examples in the link above I think I understand how it works. In the following example, provided `$a` is not null and has a property called `PropName` it will return the value of `$a.PropName` or else return null.:

```
$a = @{ PropName = 100 }
${a}?.PropName # ==> 100
```

However, I don't understand why I would use the new null-conditional operator over accessing object properties using the dot (`.`). The below example renders the same both ways and does not throw or explicitly suppress any errors:

### Dot

```
@{ PropName = 100 },
@{ PropNumber = 8675309 } | Foreach-Object {
  Write-Host ( $null -ne $_.PropName ? "PropName has a value of $($_.PropName)" : 'PropName is $null' )
}

# 1st iteration ==> PropName has a value of 100
# 2nd iteration ==> PropName is $null
```

### Null-Conditional (note the subtle change)

```
@{ PropName = 100 },
@{ PropNumber = 8675309 } | Foreach-Object {
  Write-Host ( $null -ne ${_}?.PropName ? "PropName has a value of $(${_}?.PropName)" : 'PropName is $null' )
}

# 1st iteration ==> PropName has a value of 100
# 2nd iteration ==> PropName is $null
```

So, I understand when this is meant to be used, but PowerShell already had a solution for this with simpler syntax. I guess to put it bluntly, what is the point of this operator? I can't find much documentation on this operator aside from what I linked above, and I'm assuming there must be something I'm missing. There is a similar operator for arrays (`?[]`) to conditionally return an array element or $null if the index is out of bounds, but again, PowerShell already returns `$null` without error if you go out of bounds on an array and try accessing a property.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the difference about 30 seconds after I submitted this. My testing above only tests Property members and does not take methods or strict-mode into account. But rather than delete the question, I think there is value in explaining this.

By default, Properties don't throw errors when they don't exist on an object, but you absolutely will get an `InvalidOperation` error if you try to execute a Method on a `$null` object. And strict-mode throws most of my dot-access example out entirely, as strict-mode will throw errors when you try to dot-access *any* member on a null-valued object (among other additional guardrails in place).

So in short, the `?.` and `?[]` operators are super-useful if you have objects with methods or if you are running PowerShell in strict-mode. Otherwise, in either of these cases you get to write more boilerplate code to do null checks first.